# Does it ever make sense to send useState() a variable type?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have recently started learning React, and have encountered 'useState()'.  My understanding is as follows:

- useState returns both a variable, and a function which is used to set that variable
- useState can take a parameter which is used to initialize the returned variable

(From the description on reactjs.org: "The only argument to the useState() Hook is the initial state.")

Now, I have recently encountered code similar to the following:

```
const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(Boolean);
```

It looks to me like they are sending a variable type to useState(), rather than an initial value.  This doesn't make sense to me, based on the description I have read of how useState() works.  However, I am new to React, so I am wondering whether this actually makes sense somehow.

Comment: I don't see a reason to pass the Boolean constructor into `useState`. It will have the same effect as `useState(false)`. When you pass a function to use state, react will call that function on the first render and use the return value as the initial state.

Comment: `useState` will accept a function _returning_ the default value, but why they didn't just use `false` is unclear.